# Django - How to cast "None" from url kwargs to None without repeating yourself

Tags: django, url, nonetype

I have a model like this:

```
#models.py
class Location(BaseArticle):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    parent_location = models.ForeignKey("self",
                                        blank=True,
                                        null=True,
                                        help_text="Fill in if this location is a smaller part of another location.",
                                        on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    description = HTMLField(blank=True,
                            null=True,
                            help_text="A description of the location and important features about it")

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('name', 'parent_location')
```

I decided in my urls to uniquely identify each Location through its own name, and the name of its parent-element.

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('locations/<str:parent_location_name>/<str:location_name>', wiki_views.LocationView.as_view(), name='location'),
]

# example url to location "Seedy Bar" located in "City"
# https://<DOMAIN>/locations/city/seedy bar
# example url to location "City" that does not have a parent_location
# https://<DOMAIN>/locations/none/city
```

As you can see from the examples, Locations where `parent_location` is null/None are possible. I decided to convert `None` to `"None"` for these urls, though I'm not set on what `None` gets transformed to. Now as you may realize this means that whenever I do anything with Location, I need to pay attention to convert `"None"` to `None` in the views as necessary, which gets annoying really fast.

To follow DRY I was wondering what the best way would be to deal with this, or have I designed myself into a corner here?

Edit: I believe the best solution for this might be within the Location model or its Manager. Fixing it there means this logic is handled for all views and queries, whereas a solution for this problem on the view-level would mean that the solution needs to be implemented for every view that might make a query to Location with `"None".

**What I came up with so far:**

Given that Managers are the interface through which you interact with models I checked whether they have anything and stumbled over modifying get_queryset. As I do not call get_queryset myself however, I'm not sure if functions like filter/exclude any others I might not even know about actually call it. However, I generally like this approach best as it keeps the logic on how to handle this stuff with the model/manager, where it belongs in my eyes.

Another alternative would of course be to write my own Mixin to fix this issue on the view-level, but that means I still need to remember every time that this is an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the advice of @Aayush Agrawal I just barely escaped from committing to a bad practice in this regard. In hindsight I agree, it is not a good idea to use a Manager for this, as while that might work, it would also obfuscate inputs and produce unexpected results in the future.

Thus I opted to go for the Mixin solution and Implemented the following:

```
# settings.py
NONE_STRING = 'None'



# views.py
from django.conf import settings

class ReplaceNoneMixin(object):
    """Mixin to deal with URL Parameters that represent None. This mixin takes the name of a url parameter and assumes
    that if it represents None that it has the value of settings.NONE_STRING. If the parameter is encountered with that
    value, the value is changed from NONE_STRING to None."""
    kwargs: dict
    noneable_parameters_keys: list

    def setup(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Changes the value of all url parameters specified in noneable_parameters_keys list. If the parameter has the
         settings.NONE_STRING value in kwargs then the value is set to None."""
        super().setup(request, *args, **kwargs)
        if isinstance(self.noneable_parameters_keys, str):
            self.noneable_parameters_keys = [self.noneable_parameters_keys]

        for parameter in self.noneable_parameters_keys:
            if parameter in self.kwargs and self.kwargs[parameter] == settings.NONE_STRING:
                self.kwargs[parameter] = None
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how i would do this:

Create two URLs:

```
path('locations/<str:location_name>', wiki_views.LocationView.as_view(), name='location'),
path('locations/<str:parent_location_name>/<str:location_name>', wiki_views.LocationViewWithParent.as_view(), name='location'),
```

And structure these two views like this:

```
class LocationView(generics.APIView):
    parent = None
    ... rest of your code ...

class LocationViewWithparent(LocationView):
    parent = #Your code to get the parent_location_name parameter
```

The second view will do everything the same as the parent view but override the parent variable

Comment: @PhilippDoerner This is a reply to your question about doing it in regards to URLs and views. If you want to use multiple views, a similar solution should be used for all of them. Inheritance is better than a mess of if/else and keeps the code readable and easily modifiable. If the scope of your problem is significantly different from what you've posted, you should keep the old question as-is and create a new question on StackOverflow since the questions you post are meant to be around for a long time and help others too

Comment: Thanks for the reply! (I apologize for deleting the previous comment, I realized I formulated it wrong and thus rewrote this comment hoping to be quicker than you would reply).
You also made me aware of that I forgot to mention that there are multiple other views that rely on the same pattern (or some of it) to get locations. As such this approach mostly pushes the logic from being in the view to being in the url. Cleaner for sure, but one would still need to keep this special behaviour of Location in mind whenever a new url for a view that also makes use of Locatin.

Comment: Thanks for the advice ! I entirely agree that using if-else should not be the way to go about this, it's just where the best point for the solution is. The scope of the question was luckily not limited to solving this in the view/url layer, that is just where the problem arises. That is why I looked also at maybe having a custom Manager for Location. I just don't know which explicit piece of its code I need to manipulate so that all calls to the manager to create a queryset/query first check whether any kwarg is `"None"` and change that to `None` accordingly... or whether that is possible.

Comment: @PhilippDoerner Two notes: What you have described is a data ingestion problem, NOT a database problem. It is VERY bad practice to clean data at the database layer.

Fundamentally, any data coming into your application must first be cleaned then processed. Never the other way around. The best way to do this is two URLs (Which makes sense. Two different formats of incoming data so two URLs are necessary) but if you are not able to do that, you must process this at the View.

Comment: There are a couple of ways to do this in the view:

You can create a Mixin and inherit it in all your views that sets "none" to None. Or you can use a serializer to do this aswell with DRF.

Comment: Also if the scope of the question is significantly different from what you have posted, you should post a new question with code samples of your situation.

Comment: I was not aware of the best practice there, so I take it all solutions that modify the Manager to change None before creating a QuerySet are pretty much out of the question. In that case handling it at the view seems to be the best solution to me, as it requires less code overall.

Comment: @PhilippDoerner One suggestion when doing it at the view: Whatever code you are using to get parent_id from kwargs, replace it with a function that takes the kwargs variable and replaces it with None if the value is "none". Also if you'd like to read about why doing it in the database layer is bad practice, you can search about "magic strings" and how they often cause a lot of trouble

Comment: Also please accept the answer if you are satisfied :) It incentivizes people to keep answering your questions in the future

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218568/discussion-between-philipp-doerner-and-aayush-agrawal).